# creating and initializing struct arrays

Tags: arrays, struct

I'm wanting the instances of a struct array to have their individual names, but from the examples i've seen on initializing a struct instance, I wouldn't know how to go about. but.. i'm wanting to do something like this:

```
struct st
{
....
}

struct st A;
A.element = value;

struct st B;
B.element = value;

struct st_array[2];
struct st_array[0] = A
struct st_array[1] = B;
```

but this didn't work so i'm wondering how i could go about it

Answer (score 0):

First, classes, enums, and structs are terminated with ';' following the closing bracket (or scope).
i.e.

```
struct St {
    ....
};//<--- end of scope terminator
```

Next, what exactly are you trying to do following this bit? I'm guessing  you're trying to define cases of it for use, but you're going about it entirely wrong. You need to have a member in the struct to set a value to, this can be an instance of the struct itself. Like this...

```
struct St {
    St element;
};
```

Then you can set a value to the structs member, but in this particular instance you're probably gonna want some more data members for this sturct to be of any use...

```
struct St {
     char value;
     St element;
     St(char value, St element) // struct constructor
         : this->value(value), this->element(element){} // init list
};
```

Now you can use the struct in the rest of your code simply by calling it by its identifier, which in this case would be 'St'.

Although, for what you're trying to achieve (I could be wrong) would be better suited for an enumerated value, which is (basically) a way of defining your own primitive, switchable, variable type. An example of where an enum would be useful would be something like...

```
const int MON = 0, TUE = 1, ....// rather than using "const int's"
// define them as enumerations
enum Day {MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI,SAT,SUN};

/*each enum is assigned an integer ordinal that corresponds to its location
  as it is declared, so MON == 0, TUE == 1, and so on. You can alternatively 
  assign your own value to it in an instance where the default ordinal would 
  not be useful, for instance if you wanted them as characters...*/

enum Foo {Bar = 'B', Qat = 'Q', ...};

// or

enum Ratings {PG13 = 13, R = 18, ...};
```

You would probably benefit from a resource like:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_references.htm

or

http://en.cppreference.com/w/